# Как сделать ajax формы?

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Как сделать ajax формы?

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
     Логин
     <input type="text" name="username"/>
     Пароль
     <input type="password" name="password"/>
     <button type="submit" name="submit">Войти</button>
 </form>
```

Здесь результаты (ошибка или успех)

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[name = submit]').click(function (event) {
    // Здесь надо сначала отменить всплытие события чтобы данные отправлялись не браузером а скриптом
    event.stopPropagation(); // Может не помочь
    $.ajax({ data : {
                'username': $('[name = username]').val(),
                'password': $('[name = password]').val(),
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: 'login.php',
            success: function(result) { $('#result').html(result) }
    )
});
```

Скрипт на сервере никак править не надо, вы послыаете HTTP запрос и принимаете ответ, так же как и браузер. 
Можно погуглить Jquery Ajax

Comment: По сути и jquery уже не такой котируемый фреймворк, его лучше использовать вкупе с angular или backbone

Comment: @OlegUP, Спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    var form = $(this);
    $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(result) {
        $('#result').html(result);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Нужен jQuery 2 версии

Comment: Владимир Стахеев, Спасибо!